# Can we make a Chatbot that creates a 3d environment or models

Tags: image-recognition, image-processing, chatgpt, chat-bots, environment

for example : (you lived a dream or you want to live in an environment you like )

so whenever you want that you can open UnrealEngine or blender and just using chatbot to build your own dream world , maybe it can be done with virtual reality like metaverse just write what you want to see . I think this idea is doable since virtual realities domination the world few years ago but how it can be done ??

of course I wont ask some one to do that and bring me the task ... I want someone who thinks of ideas or steps like me to do this and where to start and actually how to do this if its possible or not.